# Increasing amount of edit spam attempts?

Tags: discussion

Many of the recent suggested edits I have reviewed have been obvious spam attempts and all with similar looking content (gibberish and links).

I have been rejecting them as Vandalism, but am worried about the fact that there are many more of these than I have seen before, all of which seem to occur here on Programmers. I have not seen them on other Stack Exchange sites I am involved in.

Is this a known spammer? What more can we do?

Comment: I noticed the spam edits couple of days before your question, and send word to Stack Exchange. Didn't get a reply, but it seems to have died down a couple of days after your question, and I've just noticed a new entry in our blacklist, so we can safely assume this has been handled by the devs. Can't say if they did anything at IP level, but the blacklist entry hasn't been matched since it was added, so there's probably another safeguard in place.

Comment: Thanks for keeping me informed.

Comment: no problem. Left for vacation right after I send word to SE about the spam edits, which is why it took me a while to get back at you. AFAIK they monitor rejected edits from anonymous users, so there isn't really much we can / have to do, I pinged a community team member just because I was getting extremely annoyed rejecting spam edits all day...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are suggestions by an anonymous user. There's nothing we (as moderators) can do. The team will have IP logs, but banning people by IP is a blunt instrument.

We just have to keep vigilant and reject these edits. Based on the edits I've seen I can't see anyone approving the edits.